# Ionic: How do I change the location of build, temp, www directories

Tags: ionic-framework

I am unable to get my ionic application to launch with different build/www directories when using the "ionic serve" command

I recently purchased a NAS in order to keep my source code safe and backed up. I thought the best way to do this was move my GitHub repository to my NAS drive. (Possibly my first mistake, but that seemed to be the best option from my research). Since there is no need to keep the builds, temp files or www files on the NAS I thought the best option would be to configure the ionic application so that these files were stored locally and I assumed that it would build more quickly locally than over the network storage (given my LAN bandwidth constraints).

On reading the IONIC configuration documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/) I made the following changes to the package.json file:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_root_dir":"C:/Users/username/Development/",  
    "ionic_tmp_dir":"C:/Users/username/Development/tmp/",   
    "ionic_src_dir":"Y:/Dev/GitHub/mynewapp/src/",  
    "ionic_www_dir":"C:/Users/username/Development/www/",
    "ionic_build_dir":"C:/Users/username/Development/build/"
  }
```

C=local and Y=NAS.

After making these changes and saving the file I started the ionic server with the "ionic serve" command. However, after the build completed and the browser opened I received only a blank page. On clicking F12 the console provided the following errors:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8100/build/main.css
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:8100/build/main.js
SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'angular' is not defined
```

I checked the referenced directories above and the build and www directories were populated with data.

On reversing the changes by removing the above configuration and rerunning the "ionic serve" command the browser launched and the application ran as expected.

I have so far been unable to find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated.